# Importing the entire AOSP inside eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-source

I've downloaded the full AOSP source for my device, and was trying to import it inside eclipse to make some changes to the framework (basically it includes an alertDialog that shows when a button in the system bar is pressed and i want to edit it).

I've followed the guide on the [AOSP Documentation](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html), and also imported in my build path the `android-common_intermediates/javalib.jar` but i still get some errors, to be specific I get errors with some fields that should have been defined in one `R.java` file and I have no idea of how to find the proper R file, i even doubt it's there, maybe is it generated in a second moment or is it in another path and then my compiler script moves it to the right path?

Comment: If you want to do such a trivial change, why not extend the related class/classes and do your modifications there instead of recompiling the whole API and make your app incompatible with the official API?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood what you mean. Are you suggesting to import into eclipse only the framework paths and resolve errors?

Comment: I mean to extend a functionality (or also modify it) you usually don't need to modify the original classes but extend them. This is called [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: basically your suggestion is to import the only thing i want to edit (in this case framework.jar) and resolve dependency errors, then compile by adding new classes? since i cannot import it into eclipse properly i was also thinking: would it be possible to run something like `make` from terminal to make him compile only framework.jar? by the way, i need to edit that specific class because i need it is that class to be launched and not another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you heed the warnings in the comments above and still want an answer to the question, I may be able to help.  I frequently see similar problems, when I use eclipse to view Android source.  There are several projects that are, apparently, not built in response to "make" but that are still included by the .classpath file.  My solution is to make them by hand.

Once you've sourced build/envsetup.sh, the command "mm" will build the project in the directory you are in.  I start eclipse, find the projects whose resource definitions are missing, cd into them one by one, and use "mm" to build them.

I believe that you will find that they are all projects in the "packages" directory.

So far, this has always worked, for me.

Comment: Yes in the end i did the same thing and for now it is working without flaws

Comment: what about framework and other AOSP source code?? which is not in packages/apps/..